# Content loss when CAPTCHA modal gets reloaded? (e.g., because JavaScript from google.com is disallowed)

Tags: bug, javascript, captcha

The following just happened to me (on [softwarerecs](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/), but I guess it should be the same for all SE sites):

1. I was entering a new question.
2. When trying to post it, I was asked to solve a CAPTCHA. (*)
3. The CAPTCHA was hosted on google.com, whose JavaScript I had disabled, which means: the CAPTCHA couldn’t be loaded.
4. I allowed JS from google.com, which required a reload of the page.
5. After the reload, my question content was lost.

(* Probably because I had the question form open for many hours.)

Comment: I have a feeling the dev's will say this is status-bydesign or declined since the issue was caused by a third party plugin/script.

Comment: There is also auto draft feature that you blocked by disabling JavaScript. Just that you know. Anyway, that's NOT a bug. When you disable JavaScript, many things will be broken.

Comment: @ShadowWizard: I have JavaScript enabled for the Stack Exchange sites. Auto save for drafts usually works, but in this case (reloading the page while the CAPTCHA modal was open) it resulted in an empty question form. When I reloaded this page *again*, it showed a draft from the day before (where I opened the question page and just entered a short reminder note). When I enter something and just reload the page, the content is *not* lost. So it has to with this CAPTCHA situation.